# Flex Box: Maximum Cross Width

Tags: css, flexbox

I am trying to use CSS `flex` to achieve a simple layout:

```
┌────────────────┐
│ body           │
│   ┌────────┐   │
│   │ header │   │
│   ├────────┤   │
│   │  main  │   │
│   ├────────┤   │
│   │ footer │   │
│   └────────┘   │
└────────────────┘
```

So far, I have:

```css
body {
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
min-height: 100vh; 
}
main {
flex: 1;
}
header, main, footer {
border: thin solid #ccc;
margin: 4px;
}
```

```html
<header>
Header
</header>
<main>
Main
</main>
<footer>
Footer
</footer>
```

What property do I need to set to have the `header`, `main`, and `footer` set to the same width, up to a set maximum, while keeping them centered?

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do this with CSS grid:

```css
body {
  display:grid;
  grid-template-rows: auto 1fr auto;
  justify-content:center;
  grid-gap:4px;
  min-height: 100vh;
  margin:0;
}

header,
main,
footer {
  border: thin solid #ccc;
}
```

```html
<header>
  Header
</header>
<main>
  Main
</main>
<footer>
  Footer
</footer>
```

Or consider `inline-flex` to have a shrink-to-fit behavior:

```css
body {
  text-align:center;
  margin:0;
}
.container {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-height: 100vh;
  text-align:left;
}

main {
  flex: 1;
}

header,
main,
footer {
  border: thin solid #ccc;
  margin: 4px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<header>
  Header
</header>
<main>
  Main
</main>
<footer>
  Footer
</footer>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but how would I set the `header`, `main` and `footer` to the same width?

Comment: @Manngo but they are the same width, no?

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your code:

```
header,
main,
footer {
  min-width: 200px;  /* demo */
  max-width: 400px;  /* demo */
  border: thin solid #ccc;
  margin: 4px auto;  /* left and right auto margins for centering */
}
```

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

main {
  flex: 1;
}

header,
main,
footer {
  min-width: 200px;
  max-width: 400px;
  border: thin solid #ccc;
  margin: 4px auto;
}
```

```html
<header>Header</header>
<main>Main</main>
<footer>Footer</footer>
```